# Is there any science to explain the "weight" or "3D depth" of hardware audio vs software that some people claim?

Tags: audio

Is there any science to explain the "weight" or "3D depth" of hardware audio vs software that some people claim?

There's, I think, strong subjective evidence to suggest that the phenomenon is true. But I've not found scientific explanation as to "what creates it" or "what it is (in measurements)".

Any input?

Comment: *What* hardware audio vs *what* software?

Comment: Record them both and look at the waveforms.

Answer (score 3):

Most Audiophile stuff*) has a credibility on par with homeopathy.

It might work - provided that some sales-oriented cable manufacturer single handedly revolutionized science. But in all likelihood it is most about clever marketing and gullible buyers.

Fortunately there are test protocols to prove that sensory perceptions are different. Unfortunately, the audiophile industry does its best to avoid said protocols.

-k
*)there are some hard working, knowledgeable people in the industry. They tend to avoid outlandish claims...

Comment: I think it's not a bs phenomenon. I'm scientifically minded and I recognize it as well. I haven't done ABX test myself, but some others have. I simply recognize that no plug-in seems to sound just like a hardware API 527 or something. A particular difference is in e.g. a kind of "low-mid" bump (perhaps that's the "weight") and, yes, a kind of "the sound sounds more lively/3D" perception that's hard to explain, but you recognize it when you hear it. I think the problem is that it hasn't been studied. That there's no proper "psychoacoustic" characterization for what the phenomenon is about.